# How to deploy a Google Endpoints for Android app when using Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Android Studio and Google Endpoints for my Android application. Up until now I'm running the server locally. Can anyone tell me how to deploy the server?

Comment: You can use google applicaton kit on eclipse for deploy on local and after testing you can deploy it on Google Application engine.You can follow any beginner level tutorial provided by google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from directly from terminal. Go to the project directory then execute command

```
gradlew appengineUpdate
```

You can also deploy it from Android Studio

> Build > Deploy module to App Engine